# How to setup a cloud with a bunch of computers running ubuntu server?

Tags: server, cloud

How to setup a cloud with a bunch of computer running Ubuntu server connected in a LAN.. is it possible to access the cloud outside the LAN through internet..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.. 
http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3858961/Grow-Your-Own-Cloud-Servers-With-Ubuntu.htm has the information to build the cloud

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing (i.e. accessing the cloud infrastructure from the Internet) is commonly called a public cloud infrastructure.

A good start would be to to visit the [OpenStack Project's Getting Started](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Getting_Started) page.

This should give you first hand information on the OpenStack projects.

Comment: Am not only asking about accessing.. First What i meant is to build a Cloud with some computers within a LAN and to access it outside the LAN via internet..

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "cloud" is more an idea rather than some kind of strict protocol.

So, first you need to ask your self what exactly do you want. Do you want some kind of data storage, or data processing or something else.

Once you know what kind of "cloud computing" service you need you can ask how to set it up.

Comment: i need it for data processing.. and I found the answer to my question.. [this article](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3858961/Grow-Your-Own-Cloud-Servers-With-Ubuntu.htm) has the information to build a cloud with two computers..!!

Comment: @jaykay90: Good for you. BTW, you can answer your own question if you find a good solution.

Comment: lol.. tried it.. seems like i've to wait for another 6 hours...